# error when try to update aws codebuild pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I want to ask why codebuild step always get error like this i have no idea why?

[image]

[image]

Comment: First post the screenshots in English. Don’t presume that your regional language is a global language.

Comment: i so sorry i forgot ,i edit the image

Comment: Can you check by the CodeBuild project which is used by CodePipeline exists or not. It seems, that is missing.

Comment: Where to check ?